# Is this Bertrand's postulate-related statement valid?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

[Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate) says:

> For every $n>1$ there is always at least one prime $p$ such that $n<p<2n$.

---

Is the following statement:

> For every $n>3$ there is always at least one prime $p$ such that $F_n<p<F_{n+1}$ ($F_n$ is $n$-th Fibonacci number).

also valid?

If it is invalid, is there a finite or infinite number of $n$s such that there is no prime between $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$?

---

This question is inspired by another question. I feel intuitively that it may be interesting, but don't have enough number theory background to tackle it.

Comment: Part I: determine the smallest positive integer $a$ such that $2F_n\le F_{n+a}$...

Comment: a=2..... @abiessu

Comment: In fact the prime number theorem implies that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and sufficiently large $n$, there is a prime between $n$ and $(1 + \varepsilon) n$. For stronger results than this see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conjecture is true.

From a result of [Nagura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate#Better_results), for $n\ge 25$, there is always a prime between $n$ and $1.2n$.  Note that $F_9=34$, $F_{10}=55$, and their ratio is $1.617>1.2$.  In fact, for all $n\ge 9$, we can prove that $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}>1.2$ (*).  Hence, combining these results gives a prime between $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$ for all $n\ge 9$.  It remains merely to check the smaller Fibonacci numbers.

(*) The ratio approaches $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 1.6$ as a limit, and rather quickly.